# Automatically generate SQL INSERT statements with data that respect database constraints

Tags: sql, mysql

Here is a simple situation. (My apologies my SQL is quite rusty.)

(I am using MySQL and Java but it should not matter too much.)

Let's say I have two tables.

Here is a simple SQL statement:

A:

```
insert into patient (patient_id) values (16)
```

Now there is another table person, which has a person_id and that has to be constrained to match patient_id.

B:

```
CONSTRAINT `person_id_for_patient` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

What I am looking for is some pre-built tool, solution, etc., that might allow one to expand an insert statement such as A in order to satisfy constraints automatically.

In other words, that would automatically expand A into:

```
insert into person (person_id) values (16)
insert into patient (patient_id) values (16)
```

Any ideas?

Thank you
Misha

Comment: I assume your real tables have more than one field... What would this software enter for the remaining values? How would it guess what you were trying to put into the table?

Comment: A little research shows http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS might be a step in the right direction

Comment: I'm not that familiar with MySQL so I'm not sure if that's possible,  but wouldn't deferred constraints do what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these 2 solutions to handle your business logic requirements:

- Strongly suggest creating a stored procedure to insert into both the `person` and the `patient` tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreatePerson(IN newID int)
BEGIN
   insert into person (person_id) values (newID);
   insert into patient (patient_id) values (newID);
   --as many statements as you need. perhaps wrap in a TRANSACTION.
END;
```

This will help control the business logic. You'll have to enforce that all code NOT directly insert into the `person` using adhoc SQL. How easy/hard this is depends on your environment.

- Create a trigger for `after insert` on the `person` table to automatically insert into `patient`. [Creating triggers in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html). Triggers will definitely solve your dev problem here, but generally aren't overall a great solution, as you tend to 'forget' that they're there. Later, when you are investigating a defect/problem in your database, you may overlook the hidden logic in the trigger. [Read more opinions on triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460316).

Either way, with either of these two, you'll get the creation of a record into the `patient` after `person`.

The question then becomes - does this business rule need enforcing *the other way around*? What happens when a process tried to write into the `patient` table? Does it require that a match exist in the `person` table?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for very helpful replies.

EDIT: Here is an improved version, JDBC compliant I believe:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

class NotAllowedToInsertIntoTableException extends Exception {
    String table;
    public NotAllowedToInsertIntoTableException(String table) {
        super(table);
        this.table = table;
    }
}

class UnhandledCaseException extends Exception {
    public UnhandledCaseException() {
        super();
    }
}

class TableColumn {
    String table;
    String column;
    public TableColumn(String table, String column) {
        this.table = table;
        this.column = column;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "\"" + table + "\".\"" + column + "\"";
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof TableColumn) {
            TableColumn tableColumn = (TableColumn)obj;
            return ((table.equals(tableColumn.table)) && (column.equals(tableColumn.column)));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashCode = 1;
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (table==null ? 0 : table.hashCode());
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (column==null ? 0 : column.hashCode());
        return hashCode;
    }       
}

class KeyReference extends TableColumn {
    public KeyReference(String table, String column) {
        super(table, column);
    }
    public KeyReference(TableColumn tableColumn) {
        this(tableColumn.table, tableColumn.column);
    }
}

class ImportedKey {
    TableColumn primary;
    TableColumn foreign;
    public ImportedKey(ResultSet rs) throws Exception {
        primary = new TableColumn(rs.getString("PKTABLE_NAME"), rs.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME"));
        foreign = new TableColumn(rs.getString("FKTABLE_NAME"), rs.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME"));
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "primary " + primary.toString() + ", foreign " + foreign.toString();
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof ImportedKey) {
            ImportedKey importedKey = (ImportedKey)obj;
            return ((primary == importedKey.primary) && (foreign == importedKey.foreign));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashCode = 1;
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (primary==null ? 0 : primary.hashCode());
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (foreign==null ? 0 : foreign.hashCode());
        return hashCode;
    }       
}

class InsertStatement {
    String table;
    Map<String, Object> columnValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    public InsertStatement(String table) {
        this.table = table;
    }
    public void add(String column, Object value) {
        columnValues.put(column, value);
    }
    public String toSql(Map<KeyReference, Object> keys) throws Exception {
        String columns = null;
        String values = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> columnValue: columnValues.entrySet()) {
            String column = columnValue.getKey();
            if (columns == null) columns = column; else columns += ", " + column;
            Object value = columnValue.getValue();
            String string = null;
            if (value instanceof String) {
                string = (String) value;
            } else if (value instanceof KeyReference) {
                KeyReference keyReference = (KeyReference) value;
                if (keys.containsKey(keyReference) == false ||
                    (keys.get(keyReference) instanceof String) == false) {
                    throw new UnhandledCaseException();
                } 
                string = (String) keys.get(keyReference);
            } else {
                throw new UnhandledCaseException();
            }
            if (values == null) values = string; else values += ", " + string;
        }
        if (columns != null && values != null) {
            return "insert into " + table + " (" + columns + ") values (" + values + ")";
        } else {
            return "insert into " + table + " () values ()";
        }
    }
}

class InsertStatementList {
    List<InsertStatement> insertStatements = new Vector<InsertStatement>();
    public InsertStatementList() {
    }
    public InsertStatementList(InsertStatementList insertStatementList) {
        this.insertStatements.addAll(insertStatementList.insertStatements);
    }
    public int getTableIndex(String table) {
        int idx = 0;
        for (InsertStatement is: insertStatements) {
            if (is.table.equals(table)) return idx;
            idx++;
        }
        return -1;
    } 
    public void add(String table, String column, Object value) {
        int idx = getTableIndex(table);
        InsertStatement is = null;
        if (idx != -1) {
            is = insertStatements.get(idx);
        } else {
            is = new InsertStatement(table);
        }
        is.add(column, value);
        if (idx != -1) {
            insertStatements.set(idx, is);
        } else {
            insertStatements.add(is);
        }
    }
    public void add(TableColumn tableColumn, Object value) {
        add(tableColumn.table, tableColumn.column, value);
    }
}

public class test {

    public static final String tablesIntoWhichWeAreAllowedToInsert[] = {
        "patient", "person" 
    };

    public static boolean isDebugEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
    public static final void debug(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    public static void insertIntoDatabase(Connection conn,
                                          Map<TableColumn, Object> paramMap,
                                          Map<TableColumn, Object> given) throws Exception
    {
        InsertStatementList insertStatements = new InsertStatementList();

        // Make a copy of the map
        Map<TableColumn, Object> map = new HashMap<TableColumn, Object>();
        map.putAll(paramMap);

        // Add map elements
        for (Entry<TableColumn, Object> mapElement: map.entrySet()) {
            TableColumn tableColumn = mapElement.getKey();
            Object value = mapElement.getValue();
            insertStatements.add(tableColumn.table, tableColumn.column, value);
        }

        // Try to satisfy foreign key constraints
        DatabaseMetaData dmd = conn.getMetaData();
        boolean satisfiedConstraints = false;
        do {

            debug("---");

            //
            // What imported keys do we need?
            //

            // Avoid ConcurrentModificationException
            InsertStatementList savedInsertStatements = new InsertStatementList(insertStatements);

            List<ImportedKey> importedKeys = new Vector<ImportedKey>();
            for (InsertStatement is: savedInsertStatements.insertStatements) {          

                // Find not nullable columns
                List<TableColumn> notNullable = new Vector<TableColumn>();
                ResultSet rs = dmd.getColumns(null, null, is.table, "");
                debug("Not nullable columns:");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    if (rs.getString("IS_NULLABLE").equals("NO")) {
                        TableColumn tableColumn = new TableColumn(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"), rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
                        notNullable.add(tableColumn);
                        debug("\t" + tableColumn.toString());
                    }

                    // If we have uuid column and none in insert
                    // http://wiki.openmrs.org/display/archive/UUIDs
                    if (rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").equals("uuid") &&
                        is.columnValues.containsValue("uuid") == false) {
                        insertStatements.add(is.table, "uuid", "uuid()");               
                    }
                }

                // Find imported keys ...
                rs = dmd.getImportedKeys(null, null, is.table);
                debug("Imported keys:");
                while (rs.next()) {

                    ImportedKey importedKey = new ImportedKey(rs);

                    // ... if in given, just add
                    if (given.containsKey(importedKey.primary)) {
                        insertStatements.add(importedKey.foreign, given.get(importedKey.primary));
                    } 
                    // ... if not in map and not nullable need to insert table                  
                    else if (map.containsKey(importedKey.primary) == false && 
                            notNullable.contains(importedKey.foreign) == true) {
                        importedKeys.add(importedKey);
                        debug("\t" + importedKey.toString());
                    }
                }
            }

            //
            // Try to add tables
            //

            for (ImportedKey ik: importedKeys) {
                TableColumn primary = ik.primary;
                if (primary.column.equals(primary.table + "_id") == false) {
                    throw new UnhandledCaseException();
                }
                if (Arrays.asList(tablesIntoWhichWeAreAllowedToInsert).contains(primary.table) == false) {
                    throw new NotAllowedToInsertIntoTableException(primary.table);  
                }

                // Add to map for reference
                map.put(primary, null);

                // Add to insert statement for table
                insertStatements.add(ik.foreign.table, ik.foreign.column, new KeyReference(ik.primary));

                // Add to top of insert statements
                insertStatements.insertStatements.add(0, new InsertStatement(primary.table));
            }

            // 
            // Done?
            //

            if (importedKeys.isEmpty()) {
                satisfiedConstraints = true;
            }
        } while (satisfiedConstraints == false);

        //
        // Insert into database
        //

        debug("* --- *");

        // Keys
        Map<KeyReference, Object> keys = new HashMap<KeyReference, Object>();

        for (InsertStatement is: insertStatements.insertStatements) {
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = is.toSql(keys);
            debug(sql);

            s.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ResultSet rs = s.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                throw new UnhandledCaseException();
            }

            keys.put(new KeyReference(is.table, is.table + "_id"), rs.getString(1));

            rs.close();
            s.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Connection conn = null;

        try
        {
            String userName = "openmrs_user";
            String password = "Iw65GkNPQVOP";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openmrs";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);            

            // Test data
            Map<TableColumn, Object> map = new HashMap<TableColumn, Object>();
            map.put(new TableColumn("patient_identifier", "identifier"), "1234");
            map.put(new TableColumn("person_name", "given_name"), "'Bob'");

            // Given columns
            Map<TableColumn, Object> given = new HashMap<TableColumn, Object>();
            given.put(new TableColumn("users", "user_id"), "1");
            given.put(new TableColumn("patient_identifier_type", "patient_identifier_type_id"), "1");
            given.put(new TableColumn("location", "location_id"), "1");
            given.put(new TableColumn("tribe", "tribe_id"), "1");

            insertIntoDatabase(conn, map, given);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.rollback();
                    conn.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have whittled something together that uses Connector/J mysql-connector-java-5.1.8.jar

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

class TableColumn {
    String table;
    String column;
    public TableColumn(String table, String column) {
        this.table = table; this.column = column;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return table+"."+column;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof TableColumn) {
            TableColumn tableColumnObj = (TableColumn)obj;
            return ((table.equals(tableColumnObj.table)) && (column.equals(tableColumnObj.column)));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }   
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashCode = 1;
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (table==null ? 0 : table.hashCode());
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (column==null ? 0 : column.hashCode());
        return hashCode;
    }
}   

class InsertStatement {
    String table;
    Map<String, String> columnValues = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    public String toString(Map<String, String> tableColumnValueMap) {
        String columns = null;
        String values = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> columnValue: columnValues.entrySet()) {
            String column = columnValue.getKey();
            String value = columnValue.getValue();

            if (value.startsWith("!@#$%")) {
                String key = value.substring("!@#$%".length());
                value = tableColumnValueMap.get(key);
                if (value == null) {
                    System.out.println("Cannot find tableColumnValueMap key \"" + key + "\"");
                    System.out.println("tableColumnMap:");
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> tableColumnValueMapEntry: tableColumnValueMap.entrySet()) {
                        System.out.println("\t\"" + tableColumnValueMapEntry.getKey() +
                            "\" = \"" +
                            tableColumnValueMapEntry.getValue() +
                            "\"");
                    }
                    try { throw new Exception("Unhandled case!!!"); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }

            if (columns == null) columns = column; else columns += ", " + column;
            if (values == null) values = value; else values += ", " + value;
        }

        // http://wiki.openmrs.org/display/archive/UUIDs
        if (!table.equals("patient")) {
            String column = "uuid";
            String value = "uuid()";

            if (columns == null) columns = column; else columns += ", " + column;
            if (values == null) values = value; else values += ", " + value;
        }

        return "insert into " + table + " (" + columns + ") values (" + values + ")";
    }
}

public class test {
    // constraintMap<<table, Map<column, referencedTable>>
    static Map<String, Map<String, TableColumn>> constraintMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, TableColumn>>();

    static String columnsWeDoNotFillInAutomatically[] = { 
        "voided_by", "changed_by", "retired_by", "cause_of_death" 
    };

    static void insertIntoDatabaseHelper(Connection conn,
                                         Map<String, Map<String, String>> columnValueMapByTable,
                                         Map<TableColumn, String> given)
    {
        Vector<InsertStatement> insertStatements = new Vector<InsertStatement>();

        // Output
        System.out.println("columnValueMapByTable:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry: columnValueMapByTable.entrySet()) {
            String table = (String) entry.getKey();
            System.out.println(table);
            Map<String, String> columnValueMap = (Map<String, String>) entry.getValue();
            if (columnValueMap != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> columnValue: columnValueMap.entrySet()) {
                    String column = columnValue.getKey();
                    String value = columnValue.getValue();
                    System.out.println("\t" + column + " = \"" + value + "\"");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");         

        List<String> insertedTables = new Vector<String>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry: columnValueMapByTable.entrySet()) {
            InsertStatement is = new InsertStatement();
            is.table = (String) entry.getKey();

            Map<String, TableColumn> constraintColumnValueMap = constraintMap.get(is.table);            
            Map<String, String> columnValueMap = entry.getValue();      

            // Create statement
            if (columnValueMap != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> columnValue: columnValueMap.entrySet()) {
                    String column = columnValue.getKey();
                    String value = "'" + columnValue.getValue() + "'";

                    if (constraintColumnValueMap.containsKey(column)) {
                        System.out.println("Constrained columns should never be present in form data");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }

                    is.columnValues.put(column, value);
                }
            }

            if (constraintColumnValueMap != null) {
                // Find given columns in constrained columns - add those
                Map<String, TableColumn> remainingConstraints = new HashMap<String, TableColumn>();
                for (Map.Entry<String, TableColumn> columnTableColumn: constraintColumnValueMap.entrySet()) {
                    String column = columnTableColumn.getKey();
                    TableColumn tableColumn = columnTableColumn.getValue();
                    if (Arrays.asList(columnsWeDoNotFillInAutomatically).contains(column)) {
                        // don't fill in automatically
                    } else if (given.containsKey(tableColumn)) {
                        String givenValue = given.get(tableColumn);

                        is.columnValues.put(column, givenValue);
                    } else {
                        remainingConstraints.put(column, tableColumn);
                    }
                }               
                constraintColumnValueMap = remainingConstraints;

                // Remove columns named table_id for each table in map
                remainingConstraints = new HashMap<String, TableColumn>();
                for (Map.Entry<String, TableColumn> columnTableColumn: constraintColumnValueMap.entrySet()) {

                    String column = columnTableColumn.getKey();
                    TableColumn tableColumn = columnTableColumn.getValue();
                    if (columnValueMapByTable.containsKey(tableColumn.table) && 
                        tableColumn.column.equals(tableColumn.table + "_id")) {
                        if (!insertedTables.contains(tableColumn.table)) {

                            // Is table included at all
                            if (!columnValueMapByTable.containsKey(tableColumn.table)) {
                                try { throw new Exception("Unhandled case!!!"); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                                System.out.println("tableColumn: " + tableColumn);
                                System.exit(1);                                                         
                            } else {

                                Map<String, Map<String, String>> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
                                for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> newEntry: columnValueMapByTable.entrySet()) {
                                    String table = newEntry.getKey();
                                    Map<String, String> map = newEntry.getValue();

                                    if (!table.equals(is.table) && !table.equals(tableColumn.table)) {
                                        // preserve order
                                        newMap.put(table, map);
                                    } else if (table.equals(is.table)) {
                                        newMap.put(tableColumn.table, columnValueMapByTable.get(tableColumn.table));
                                        newMap.put(table, map);
                                    }
                                }
                                insertIntoDatabaseHelper(conn, newMap, given);
                                return;                             
                            }

                            System.out.println("insertedTables:");
                            for (String table: insertedTables) {
                                System.out.println("\t" + table);
                            }
                        } else {
                            String value = "!@#$%" + tableColumn.toString();

                            is.columnValues.put(column, value);
                        }
                    } else {
                        remainingConstraints.put(column, tableColumn);                  
                    }
                }               
                constraintColumnValueMap = remainingConstraints;
            }

            // Any constrained columns? If so, add those tables to map (empty) and restart
            // (ordered map)
            if (constraintColumnValueMap != null &&
                !constraintColumnValueMap.isEmpty()) {
                Map<String, Map<String, String>> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
                for (Map.Entry<String, TableColumn> columnTableColumn: constraintColumnValueMap.entrySet()) {
                    String column = columnTableColumn.getKey();
                    TableColumn tableColumn = columnTableColumn.getValue();
                    System.out.println("\tConstraint: " + column + " = \"" + tableColumn.toString() + "\"");

                    if (!newMap.containsKey(tableColumn.table)) {
                        newMap.put(tableColumn.table, null);
                    } else {
                        try { throw new Exception("Unhandled case!!!"); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }                   
                newMap.putAll(columnValueMapByTable);
                insertIntoDatabaseHelper(conn, newMap, given);
                return;
            }

            insertStatements.add(is);
            insertedTables.add(is.table);
        }

        // Execute inserts
        Map<String, String> tableColumnValueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (InsertStatement is: insertStatements) {
            try {
                Statement s = conn.createStatement();
                String sql = is.toString(tableColumnValueMap);
                System.out.println("Sql: \"" + sql + "\"");
                int rows = s.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                ResultSet rs = s.getGeneratedKeys();
                if (!rs.next()) {
                    try { throw new Exception("Unhandled case!!!"); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                    System.exit(1);
                }           
                tableColumnValueMap.put(is.table + "." + is.table + "_id", rs.getString("GENERATED_KEY"));
                rs.close();
                s.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                sqle.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    // map - TableColumn, value to insert
    // given - TableColumn, value which are known (like user_id)
    public static void insertIntoDatabase(Connection conn,
                                          Map<TableColumn, String> map,
                                          Map<TableColumn, String> given) 
    {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> columnValueMapByTable = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

        // Find all columns that are in a single table
        for (Map.Entry<TableColumn, String> entry: map.entrySet()) {
             Map<String, String> columnValueMap = null;

            // Does table exist?
            TableColumn tableColumn = (TableColumn) entry.getKey();
            if (columnValueMapByTable.containsKey(tableColumn.table)) {             
                columnValueMap = (Map<String, String>) columnValueMapByTable.get(tableColumn.table);
            } else {                
                columnValueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            }
            columnValueMap.put(tableColumn.column, (String) entry.getValue());
            columnValueMapByTable.put(tableColumn.table, columnValueMap);
        }

        // Helper
        insertIntoDatabaseHelper(conn, columnValueMapByTable, given);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        boolean exception = false;

        try
        {
            String userName = "openmrs_user";
            String password = "Iw65GkNPQVOP";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/information_schema";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

            // find all constraints
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            s.executeQuery("select table_name, column_name, referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name " +
                "   from key_column_usage " +
                "   where table_schema = 'openmrs' and referenced_table_schema != ''");
            ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String table = rs.getString("table_name");
                String column = rs.getString("column_name");
                Map<String, TableColumn> columnValueMap = null;
                if (constraintMap.containsKey(table)) {             
                    columnValueMap = constraintMap.get(table);
                } else {                
                    columnValueMap = new HashMap<String, TableColumn>();
                }
                TableColumn referencedColumn = new TableColumn(rs.getString("referenced_table_name"), rs.getString("referenced_column_name"));
                columnValueMap.put(column, referencedColumn);
                constraintMap.put(table, columnValueMap);
            }
            rs.close();
            s.close();

            // output
            System.out.println("Constraints: ");
            for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, TableColumn>> entry: constraintMap.entrySet()) {
                String table = entry.getKey();
                System.out.println(table);

                Map<String, TableColumn> columnValueMap = entry.getValue();
                for (Map.Entry<String, TableColumn> newEntry: columnValueMap.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println("\t" + newEntry.getKey() + ": " + newEntry.getValue().toString());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
            }
        }

        if (exception) System.exit(1); 

        try
        {
            String userName = "openmrs_user";
            String password = "Iw65GkNPQVOP";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openmrs";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);            

            // Test data
            Map<TableColumn, String> map = new HashMap<TableColumn, String>();
            map.put(new TableColumn("patient_identifier", "identifier"), "1234");
            map.put(new TableColumn("person_name", "given_name"), "Bob");

            // Given columns
            Map<TableColumn, String> given = new HashMap<TableColumn, String>();
            given.put(new TableColumn("users", "user_id"), "1");
            given.put(new TableColumn("patient_identifier_type", "patient_identifier_type_id"), "1");
            given.put(new TableColumn("location", "location_id"), "1");
            given.put(new TableColumn("tribe", "tribe_id"), "1");

            insertIntoDatabase(conn, map, given);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.rollback();
                    conn.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
            }
        }
    }
}
```