# Adding a XOR constraint via Laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to build a table of this structure using Laravel's migrations feature:

```
------------------------------------
| Data  | Rules | Allow | Restrict |
------------------------------------
| item1 | rule1 | 1,3   |   null   |
| item2 | rule2 | null  |  2,5,6   |
------------------------------------
```

As in, for each entry either Allow or Restrict must possess a not null value, but not both. I've found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447880/adding-an-one-out-of-two-not-null-constraint-in-postgresql?#comment78405340_5447947) which sounds like the condition I need, but I need to express it in a format understandable to Laravel.

Comment: Is there a condition at which both `allow` and `restrict` would both have values?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy There isn't. Only one of them should have a value within a row.

Comment: I think you should fix this in your model and use the insert event.

Comment: @ThomasMoors So if I understood your suggestion right, the check should be performed on the PHP level and not by the database engine I'm using? I could see it working, but I'm curious whether it's possible to add such a constraint via migrations.

Comment: Maybe you can give them nullable and fix the solution in the frontend. Just think these are checkboxes. True or False. But of course this could be a temporary solution.

Comment: Make a proper data model. Having an inapplicable null as a value in a table is very bad.

Comment: Migrations add nothing new to the table addressing the limitations of SQL. It just is a means to make structural changes visible in version control and be able to revert them when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 good solutions

1. **Seperate the data in 2 tables**

Table1 -> data, rules, constraint (FK)

Table2-> id (PK, referenced by Table1), content (allow/restrict numbers), isAllow(bool)

That way you do the constraint in the database. This is the better solution, because now you don't have `null` values in your database. Normalisation is a good thing.

2. **Use the event listener to check before insert**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events

```
public function creating(Table1 $t1)
{
       // check if 1 is null and 1 is not null before creating
}
```

Comment: Thanks, especially about the idea of a boolean variable meant to distinguish allow from restrict.

Comment: sure no problem! if you ever need a third "type" you can always switch to tinyInt / enum