# SQL Oracle - Double CONSTRAINT NOT NULL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to create a table in PL/SQL and this table need to have a CONSTRAINT on two attribut. I explain:

One of this two objects "com_name" and "com_nickname" need to be checked, if the both are it's ok, but at least one need to be filled.

I'm a beginner and I can't understand how can I make it work

*

> CONSTRAINT ch_com_name_nickname           CHECK (com_name = NOT NULL
>   OR com_nickname = NOT NULL)

*

This is not working.

Comment: 'Not working' isn't very helpful, it's better to say what you expect and what you actually get. But you need `IS NOT NULL`, not `= NOT NULL`. Also why have you mentioned PL/SQL?

Comment: Also [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447880/adding-an-one-out-of-two-not-null-constraint-in-postgresql), which is PostgreSQL not Oracle but same syntax' [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5658457/266304).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is `column_name IS NOT NULL`. You don't need the =.

Answer (score -1):

Why do u want do it by CONSTRAINT?!

This kind of task solves not like that.

You can simply check it in your logic (in procedure or function).

Comment: +1 I just started to learning SQL that's why I don't know how use others stuff, I will try to improve my code during this week ! Thank you for your advice !

Comment: A check constraint is the correct thing to use for this. It's fine and good to have application logic make sure it inserts the right things, but it should be *as well as* a check constraint, not instead of one. Having a check constraint (a) saves you if the application logic is somehow broken, and (b) still applies if the application is bypassed - if someone inserts directly into the table.