# Limit number of records using trigger and constraints in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, constraints

I have a table called BFFs, that stores userID, and best friend's userID and I would like to restrict that table to have exactly 3 number of best friends for each different user.

I mean if the table structre is:

```
BFFs(userID, userID)
```

and records are:

```
(3286, 1212)
(3286, 4545)
(3286, 7878)
```

And in that case, if user with ID 3286 should not be allowed to have a new record such as (3286, xyzt).

I wrote this trigger but I'm not sure:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BFFControl
BEFORE INSERT ON BFFs
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    numberOfBFFs INTEGER;
    max_BFFs INTEGER := 3;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numberOfBFFs
    FROM BFFs
    WHERE sender =: NEW.sender

    IF :OLD.sender =: NEW.sender THEN
        RETURN;
    ELSE
        IF numberOfBFFs >= max_BFFs THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Users are allowed to have at most thre friends.');
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

How should I restrich this on relational tables through assertions or triggers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another column, `FriendNumber` and a Foreign Key constraint to a reference table with exactly 3 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE Three
( friendNumber TINYINT NOT NULL 
, PRIMARY KEY (friendNumber)
) ;

INSERT INTO Three(friendNumber) 
  VALUES
    (1), (2), (3) ;

CREATE TABLE BFFs
( userID       INT NOT NULL 
, friendID     INT NOT NULL
, friendNumber TINYINT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (userID, friendID)
, UNIQUE (userID, friendNumber)
, FOREIGN KEY userID
    REFERENCES Person(userID)
, FOREIGN KEY friendID
    REFERENCES Person(userID) 

, FOREIGN KEY friendNumber           --- this ensures that a user can have
    REFERENCES Three(friendNumber)   --- max of 3 friends
) ;
```

Then you can add:

```
INSERT INTO BFFs 
  (userID, friendID, friendNumber)
VALUES
  (3286, 1212, 1) ,
  (3286, 4545, 2) ,
  (3286, 7878, 3) ;
```

---

or as suggested by @gbn, to something like this (so the column is auto-filled):

```
INSERT INTO BFFs 
    (userID, friendID, friendNumber)
  SELECT 
       3286 AS userID
     , 8989 AS friendID
     , COALESCE(
         ( SELECT MIN(Three.friendNumber)
           FROM Three 
             LEFT JOIN BFFs AS b  
               ON  b.friendNumber = Three.friendNumber
               AND b.userID = 3286
           WHERE b.friendNumber IS NULL
         ), 4
       ) AS friendNumber
  FROM dual
```

Comment: can you see the edit of my question, what are the differences between your answer and my trigger ?

Comment: Triggers are hard to debug. I usually avoid them when a constraint solution exists.

Comment: While they are not pure evil, read on this: [Are database triggers evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460316/are-database-triggers-evil)

Comment: And MySQL had some issues with triggers-cascading FKs combination, not sure if that is resolved.

Comment: So in this case, if I want to add friend, should I first add into the table Three, then into BFFs ?

Comment: No, no, table Three stays locked and out of touch of everyone. You add rows as in the example above. (editing)

Comment: So I need to keep track of number of friends that each user have before I make the adding proccess, because I'm writing the schema but people use it so they do not know the background, they sometimes add friends one by one, so in any of that case should I make the sql statement programmatically ?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem with this approach. You can't have the `friendNumber` auto-filled by the database. Well, you can with MyISAM but then you can't have FKs which is a funny situation.

Comment: You can leave it unanswered in case someone knows some better approach (answered questions get less attention). Or make another question of how this can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ypercubes' answer (whcih leverages DRI to enforce your rule), you can also LEFT JOIN with MIN to get the next of 1, 2 or 3 from the Three table per userID