# Constraint at database table level instead of function

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, constraints

I have the following select statement which I am using in a function to check overlapping of records and this function is called from application front end.

```
SELECT count(*),product_no 
from products p where lower(p.PRODUCT_REG_NO) ='GB-UNIGAS' 
and (NVL (p.return_date, p.end_date) >= '01-Jan-2015') 
and p.product_no in (select product_no from PRODUCT_MASTER  where  EXPIRED='N' 
                    and product_no  = p.product_no)
```

Instead of a function to check overlapping of records I would like to create a constraint in table so that even at database level there will not be any inserts or updates.

How can I create a constraint with the above sql statement?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Use a BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE trigger http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm (look 3/4 of the way down, at "Trigger for Complex Check Constraints: Example")

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but I'd strongly recommend using to_date() with a defined date format instead of sth like NVL (p.return_date, p.end_date) >= '01-Jan-2015'). Otherwise, your application won't work properly for other locales.

Comment: @lc.It is better to have constraints or triggers to implement business rules? Regards

Comment: A trigger is the way to do this - but do read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460316/are-database-triggers-evil first. In my experience, triggers tend to need a very high payback to pay for the additional complexity; if you've had real-world problems with this, consider it, but if it's a "just in case", I would probably not create the trigger....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping that kind of logic in a stored procedure is a good choice. Try to implement that logic in triggers and in some way or another you will end up looking at

```
ORA-04091: table <your table> is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

For example having implemented that in a trigger will allow you to use `insert` like

```
insert into <Yourtable> (<col1>...<coln>)
   values(val1... valn)
```

But you will definitely get a `mutating table` error if you try to execute `insert` like this one

```
 insert into <Yourtable> (<col1>...<coln>)
    select col1, .. coln 
      from some_table
```

If you  do not want to use a stored procedure, your other choice might be a `view` and `instead of trigger`

```
Create or replace view <ViewName> as
  select *
    from your_table;

 create or replace trigger <Trigger_name> 
   instead of insert on <View_Name>
 begin
   -- your logic
 end;
```

**IN ADDITION**

Also to enforce business rules though constraints (`CHECK` constraint), you can combine `CHECK` constraints and `materialized view` as follows:
Create materialized view (do not forget to create `materialized view log` before) for your table that would query data violating your business rules constraints.

```
 Create materialized view MV_1
  refresh complete on commit as
  --here goes your query
  -- selecting data you want to raise exception on
```

Add `check` constraint that will always be false. Something like this

```
alter table MV_1 add constraint CHK check(1=2) deferrable;
```

Having done that you will get `check constraint <..> violated` when you try to insert data in your table that violate your business rule constraints.

Comment: I was getting the problem of mutating error and I tried your solution. Mutating issue resolved, however trigger did not fire and not application error was raised. What could be the reason for this? Regards

Comment: you have to insert in a view not in the base table

Comment: oh yes, you are spot on again. Thanks

Comment: One more thing, for these kind of things like applying business rules do you recommend stored procedures/functions or triggers or constraints? Regards

Comment: It's better to use stored procedure or procedures grouped in a package  and/or constraints to enforce business rules

Comment: As mentioned in my original post how this can be done using constraints to enforce my logic? Thanks

Comment: Caveat programmor - we shall now read from the Book of Relations, chapter 2, verses 9 through 21 - "And then St. Codd said, 'Oh Lord, bless this, thy holy database design', and the Lord did bless it. Then the Lord said, 'First shall be the relations and the tuples, and the fields in their multiplicity. Next shall be the constraints, that the data shall be fair to look upon. And next shall be the triggers, but rememberest thou this - THOU SHALT IMPLEMENT NO APPLICATION LOGIC IN TRIGGERS or, being naughty in my sight, thou shalt suffer greatly".  So, like, hey, what God wants, God gets...  :-)

Comment: @Polppan You cannot use `check` constraints on base table to enforce that kind of rules, simply because they single-table, single_row constraints and cannot handle that. But you can use them in combination with materialized views. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov many thanks for your valuable suggestions and comments. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a Before Insert or update Trigger, check your condition, and raise an error if the new data don't meet your requeriments. This [link](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/85427/2/) will help you.