# automatically delete products of a deleted category in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables:

Table **Product**

```
ProductID     ProductName      CategoryName    Price
102           keyboard         PC parts        800
103           mouse            PC parts        900
```

Table **Category**

```
CategoryID   CategoryName
981          PC parts
```

If I delete a category, How do I would like to automatically delete the products under it using trigger...

Answer (score 3):

Actually you may not use `Trigger` here, the only way you do create a *FOREIGN KEY* constraint that has `DELETE CASCADE` flag set

```
CREATE TABLE Category
(
    CategoryID   INT,
    Categoryname VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (CategoryID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (Categoryname)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Product
(
    ProductID    INT,
    ProductName  VARCHAR(50)  ,  
    CategoryID   INT ,
    Price        DECIMAL(10,2),
    CONSTRAINT p_pk PRIMARY KEY (ProductID),
    CONSTRAINT p_uq UNIQUE (ProductName),
    CONSTRAINT p_fk FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID)
         REFERENCES Category(CategoryID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
GO
```

when you try to delete some `Category` on the `Category` table, it automatically deletes its child rows since table `Product` is dependent on table `Category`

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee83dd/2)

Comment: And why would a trigger be forbidden here? If he creates it as an instead of delete trigger, you won't run into the FK violation and can do the original delete at the end, no?

Comment: @BenThul yep good point, but i not fan of triggers [*see here*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/460343/491243) :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use on delete cascade to delete data from both tables.